# Disable the huge first result display when it shows sitelinks in Google Search

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

How can I disable this huge first result from displaying when I run a search in Google? It shows on big sites, CNN, BBC, etc.

[image: google search results with sitelinks]

I'm using Google Chrome, is there a way to hide or disable the site links from showing on my end?

Comment: You would need some sort of Greasemonkey-ish script.

Comment: Found this posted on google blog:
http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/evolution-of-sitelinks-expanded-and.html

Nothing about disabling this ^£^"!$

Answer (score 1):

Disable it as a user or a webmaster? This is in superuser so assuming its not for a site you control (if it is, use Google Webmaster Tools).

As @MikeKusold pointed out, Greasemonkey is the better option if you use Firefox (or any equivalent for your browser). Looking at the page structure in Firebug, it doesn't seem too hard to write css for a user-defined style to hide them all either; again this would depend on browser support.

Edit: Overlooked that you're using Chrome, don't know if it has a GM equivalent but user style sheets should be an option.

Comment: Disable as a user.